# what is the maximum number of queries

Tags: mysql

What is the maximum number of queries that can be run in a dedicated server with 4 GB of RAM in one instance.

I am running a cron job that may contains queries near to one hundred thousand.its queries running in a loop, queries are simple queries selecting 3 fields with integer fields.

please advice

Comment: check the one query time( that need to be run several times in cron job) in mysql and multiply with 100 thousand

Comment: if you are not overloading memory, than your query can run for ever. i run a report that make multiple request to the data base and as long as i clear the data after each loop i can go on for ever.

Comment: @diEho single Query took 0.0003 sec.

Comment: @Ibrahim Diallo "i clear the data" i am creating an array with 5 values to insert into data base after running some number of queries.will the performance improve if i clear the array after each insert to database?

Comment: @user494559 No. That will not affect performance in a noticeable way.

Comment: @user494559 there wont be performance gain, because you will always be using almost the same amount of data in each loop. you clearing the data/ overwriting the same variables will simply keep your memory in at same level, avoiding memory overload. I use the `unset($variable)` function to clear the data just to be safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

42, of course. The 43rd query breaks it. No, really :-)

*There is no upper limit on the number of queries* -- the loop can run all day. Unless there is some form of parallel code (i.e. threads), each query *from the cron-job* will run in series (sends query, processes result, sends query, processes...) and thus *the number of total queries is irrelevant* in terms of memory requirements.

There *is*, however, a potential (if absolutely absurd) limit with updates/inserts/deletes that *run within a single transaction*. This is because the transaction needs to be able to be rolled-back. (I am not sure if this is bound by storage, main memory, or otherwise.)

Happy coding.

---

**Since this is a long-running job, take note:** If the cron-job "runs into" the next cron-job (does not complete in time), then serious issues can result as the same "job" may be executing multiple times! This ugly situation can quickly spiral out of control if the cron-jobs keep cascading into each other: each concurrently running "job" will place more burden on the database server.

Comment: when one cron job is finished it loads another one that is from one url it goes to another url eg domain.com/cron/job1 redirects to domain.com/cron/job2 so will that be a problem?

Comment: It's not my code ;-) Just a warning and something to keep an eye on. The issue described occurs from [accidental] multiple *concurrent* executions of a job. It still doesn't affect the maximum number of queries, but it *could* lead to other resource starvation (imagine 10,000 cron jobs trying to talk to poor MySQL).